# How to wake up the GUI thread in XCB?

Tags: qt, gtk, x11, xlib, xcb

My app is waiting on a thread to finish. When the thread finishes its thing, I want to update the GUI. The GUI thread is blocked in xcb_wait_for_event().

Is this possible with XCB? How does Qt, GTK, FLTK etc. implement this basic GUI problem in terms of the XCB API?

Answer (score 2):

In Qt, you should connect a (queued) signal emitted by your thread to a slot on a GUI thread object.  The slot invocation is then processed by the event loop, just like the spontaneous events from e.g. user input.

From [Maya Posch's excellent article on using QThread](https://mayaposch.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/how-to-really-truly-use-qthreads-the-full-explanation/):

```
class Worker : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Worker();
    ~Worker();

public slots:
    void process();

signals:
    void finished();
    void error(QString err);

private:
    // add your variables here
};

void Worker::process() {
    // allocate resources using new here
    qDebug("Hello World!");
    emit finished();
}
```

In the GUI thread:

```
QThread* thread = new QThread;
Worker* worker = new Worker();
worker->moveToThread(thread);
connect(worker, SIGNAL(error(QString)), this, SLOT(errorString(QString)));
connect(thread, SIGNAL(started()), worker, SLOT(process()));
connect(worker, SIGNAL(finished()), thread, SLOT(quit()));
connect(worker, SIGNAL(finished()), worker, SLOT(deleteLater()));
connect(thread, SIGNAL(finished()), thread, SLOT(deleteLater()));
thread->start();
```

The line you are interested in is

```
connect(worker, SIGNAL(error(QString)), this, SLOT(errorString(QString)));
```

Now go and read [How To Really, Truly Use QThreads; The Full Explanation](https://mayaposch.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/how-to-really-truly-use-qthreads-the-full-explanation/).

Comment: Sorry, I was interested in how the various toolkits _implement_ this on top of XCB, not how to do it _with_ the toolkit APIs. I want to do this without any toolkit. I changed the question, hopefully it's more clear now.

Comment: Ah, I see.  I'll write a different answer for that, but leave this here in case it's useful to future readers.

Answer (score 2):

The way it works in Qt appears to be that the `xcb_wait_for_event()` runs repeatedly in a thread of its own.  Each time it receives an event, it posts a message on the `QApplication`'s shared message queue.  User threads may also add messages to the `QApplication`'s shared message queue, by means of queued signals (see my other answer).

The user application can now read events from the shared message queue (e.g. using `qApp->exec()`) and receive a mixture of spontaneous UI events and internal signals from other threads.

For more reading, I suggest the Qt5 sources, beginning with `src/plugins/platforms/xcb/qxcbconnection.cpp` - look at `QXcbEventReader::run`.

Comment: Thanks. It does seem like implementing my own queue and putting the XCB loop on another thread is the only way to go (bummer). I still have a faint hope for a simpler solution, so I'm gonna wait for more answers a little while longer.

Answer (score 0):

[stackoverflow.com/questions/8794089/how-to-send-key-event-to-application-using-xcb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8794089/how-to-send-key-event-to-application-using-xcb)

Note the warning of a potential security how, and a way to use xtest to avoid it. I wonder if you might rather wait on a signal? They aren't as scary and mysterious they seem to the uniniated. There's a great book by Michael Kerrisk:The Linux Programming Interface A Linux and UNIX System Programming Handbook which explains about it.